# I want to a create a moving label

Tags: python, tkinter

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import keyboard
import time

a = 120
root = tk.Tk()
root.state('zoomed')
root.configure(bg='white')
root.resizable(False, False)
a = 30
x = 0


def increase():
    global a
    a += 10


def ar():
    for i in range(50):
        labele1.place(x=120, y=a)
        root.after(1000, increase)


c1 = Canvas(root, width=700, height=700, bg='gray95')
c1.place(x=450, y=60)
labele1 = tk.Label(c1, text='_______', font='Calibri 20')
startbutton = tk.Button(text='Başla', command=ar)
startbutton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I want to create a moving label which moves per second. Everything looks clear but it doesn't work well. I want to make a car race app but first the walls should move back and it exit the project

Comment: Would appreciate taking a look and accepting an answer to mark the question closed.

Answer (score 2):

The idea to use `root.after` is correct, but the implementation is wrong. Just because you update the value of `a` inside a function, tkinter will not automatically update that value with its widget unless you manually ask it to. So what you can do is:

- Make the label a canvas object (recommended since you will be making a game and canvas is closer to give you tools you need):

```
def ar():
    global a
    a += 10 # Increase the value of a

    c1.coords('wall', [120, a]) # Change the coord of the tag 'wall'
    root.after(25, ar) # Repeat this function every 25 ms

....

labele1 = tk.Label(c1, text='_______', font='Calibri 20')
c1.create_window(120, a, window=labele1, tags='wall') # Initial coords -> x=120, y=30
```

- Change the location of the label using `place_configure`:

```py
def ar():
    global a
    a += 10 # Increase the value of a

    labele1.place_configure(y=a)
    root.after(25, ar) # Repeat this function every 25 ms

....

labele1 = tk.Label(c1, text='_______', font='Calibri 20')
labele1.place(x=120, y=a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Plus checking frame size and decreasing functions.
the main problem was a minor bug which you should change in line 37.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import keyboard
import time

a = 120
root = tk.Tk()
root.state('zoomed')
root.configure(bg='white')
root.resizable(False, False)
a = 30
x = 0

moving_rate = 10
max_y = 600
min_y = 30

flag_mov_func= 1
def moving_func(): #increase or decrease function
    global a
    global flag_mov_func

    if flag_mov_func :
        a += moving_rate
        if  a + moving_rate == max_y: #simple logic bouncing if it ends
            flag_mov_func=0
    elif flag_mov_func==0 :
        a -= moving_rate
        if  a - moving_rate == min_y:
            flag_mov_func=1
def ar():

    moving_func() 
    labele1.place(x=120, y=a) 
    root.after(1000, ar)

flag_is_called=1
def button1(): #new update on code to make the button work once.
    global  flag_is_called
    if flag_is_called:
        flag_is_called=0
        ar()

c1 = Canvas(root, width=700, height=700, bg='gray95')
c1.place(x=450, y=60)
labele1 = tk.Label(c1, text='_______', font='Calibri 20')
startbutton = tk.Button(text='Başla', command=button1)
startbutton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The loop just happens once, then why not just remove it?

Comment: it was the question code lol @DelriusEuphoria

Comment: hi ı notice a problem now sorry about that but it get faster when we click button more than a time ıs there any way to prevent it?

Comment: sorry my english is bad guys :((

Comment: ok check the code. updated @MehmetKılınçkaya